# How to get value before and behind decimal point in NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c

> NSString *number = @"34.56";

how to get the `34` and `56`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NSArray *items = [number componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
```

so the 34 will be index 0, and the 56 will be index 1

then you can make the string, float or int